# Can't use ConfigurationManager in vb.net framework 2.0 and VB2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

Our company use VB.NET framework 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005

Visual Studio 2005 Can't install nuget package

how can i use that Imports System.Configuration ?

I declare import **System.Configuration**

```
        If IsNothing(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ZipPage")) Then
            strUrl = "http://test.htm"
        ElseIf ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ZipPage").Length > 0 Then
            strUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ZipPage").ToString
        End If
```

that result is **name 'ConfigurationManager' is not declared.**

Comment: There's no such thing as "VB.NET standard 2.0" as far as I'm aware. I thought maybe you meant .NET Standard 2.0 but that's certainly not supported by VS 2005. Do you just mean version 2.0 of the .NET Framework?

Comment: Anyway, the `ConfigurationManager` class is declared in the System.Configuration.dll assembly so you simply add a reference to that assembly to your project.

Comment: thank you .I was mistaken What I mean is ".NET Framework version 2.0" rather than "VB.NET standard 2.0".